# Use apply() to a subset of dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am a newbie in this world of R. From whatever I have read, I know that `apply()` is used to iterate over each row/column in a matrix/vector/dataframe.

I have statement in my code:

```
a$count <- apply(a[1:9,],1,countRows,species="setosa")
```

The `coutRows` function is as follows:

```
countRows <- function(x,species){
    count <- sum(iris$sl == x['sl'] & iris$sw == x['sw'] & iris$Species == species)
}
```

My intention is to operate over only the first 9 rows in `a` and add some values to the `count` column using whatever computation that is done in `countRows()`. This is why I make use of `a[1:9,]` as the first argument of  `apply()`.

For some reason, `apply()` operates on the complete dataframe. The content of `a` at the end of execution of above statement is shown below:

```
     sl   sw count    species
1   low  low     1     setosa
2   mid  low     0     setosa
3  high  low     0     setosa
4   low  mid    32     setosa
5   mid  mid     1     setosa
6  high  mid     0     setosa
7   low high    12     setosa
8   mid high     4     setosa
9  high high     0     setosa
10  low  low     1 versicolor
11  mid  low     0 versicolor
12 high  low     0 versicolor
13  low  mid    32 versicolor
14  mid  mid     1 versicolor
15 high  mid     0 versicolor
16  low high    12 versicolor
17  mid high     4 versicolor
18 high high     0 versicolor
19  low  low     1  virginica
20  mid  low     0  virginica
21 high  low     0  virginica
22  low  mid    32  virginica
23  mid  mid     1  virginica
24 high  mid     0  virginica
25  low high    12  virginica
26  mid high     4  virginica
27 high high     0  virginica
```

I expect the remaining 18 rows to contain 0 under `count` column because I have set everything to 0 initially.

Am I doing anything wrong in the `apply()` statement?

Comment: There are two problems, 1) you are assigning the output to entire 'a' i.e. `a$count` 2) You may need the transpose

Comment: Problem #1 was the major issue. I solved it this way `a[1:9,'count'] <- apply(a[1:9,],1,countRows,species="setosa")`. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: What is `countRows` function doing?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comments, the narrow solution to your problem is to assign just to the bits of `count` you want to change:

```
a[1:9,'count'] <- apply(a[1:9,],1,countRows,species="setosa")
```

However, in looking at what you *seem* to be trying to do here, I have an alternate suggestion.

This is just to make up some data that look like yours:

```
cutnum <- ggplot2::cut_number
my_iris <- with(iris,
     data.frame(sw=cutnum(Sepal.Width,3,labels=c("low","mid","high")),
                sl=cutnum(Sepal.Length,3,labels=c("low","mid","high")),
                species=Species))
```

Now `table` will get counts of each row type, with the results as (in this case) a 3x3x3 array, and `as.data.frame` will convert the table to long format ...

```
as.data.frame(table(my_iris))
```

The results look like this:

```
      sw   sl    species Freq
 1   low  low     setosa    2
 2   mid  low     setosa   15
 3  high  low     setosa   28
 4   low  mid     setosa    0
 5   mid  mid     setosa    0
 ...
```